# Is there any way to return from JFileChooser.showOpenDialog() programmatically?

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, jython, jfilechooser

The context is here is unit testing: at the end of a test, at `tearDown`, if a `JFileChooser` is left "hanging" (i.e. displayed), I want to force it to return with a "Cancelled" value.

The problem is that, otherwise, the `actionPerformed()` where I've called `showOpenDialog` (a blocking method) continues to live on... I need to close down that `Runnable`.

NB the `Runnable` running `actionPerformed` is of course running in the EDT.  But despite this, the framework is capable of starting another "event pump": my understanding is that this is the quite normal and correct behaviour when you do `JFileChooser.showOpenDialog` in the EDT: similar functioning to calling one of the `JOptionPane.showXXX` static methods in the EDT.

I also want to avoid a "testing-contrived" solution to this: in other words, the application code must be sufficient for itself, and not use tortuous or unnatural mechanisms in the knowledge that it is going to be run by testing code for which it needs to provide a "handle".

PS I am actually using Jython, rather than Java, and I am using the Python `unittest` module, rather than a Java-based unit testing framework.  But this doesn't change the principles involved...

PPS ***(later)*** I have devised a method which I regard as rather "precarious": this involves digging down into the `JFileChooser` to identify a `JButton` with `getText()` == "Cancel".  Sorry, it's written in Jython, but it should be pretty easy to grasp even to those who know no Python:

```
def close_main_frame():
    self.main_frame.dispose()
    self.cancel_button = None
    def explore_descendant_comps( container, method, breadth_first = False, depth = 0 ):
        for component in container.components:
            if isinstance( component, java.awt.Container ):
                if breadth_first:
                    method( component, depth )
                explore_descendant_comps( component, method, breadth_first, depth + 1 )
                if not breadth_first:
                    method( component, depth )
    def identify_cancel_button( comp, depth ):
        if isinstance( comp, javax.swing.JButton ) and comp.text == 'Cancel': 
            self.cancel_button = comp
    explore_descendant_comps( self.main_frame.analysis_file_chooser, identify_cancel_button )
    if self.cancel_button:
        self.cancel_button.doClick()
    else:
        raise Exception()

self.edt_despatcher.run_in_edt( close_main_frame, False )
```

This is "precarious" not least because the "Cancel" text of the button may be replaced by something with another name in another language...

Comment: actually there is a cancelSelection() method on chooser. Can't you directly call if you have the component? May be you need to check is instanceOf JFileChooser on the component before calling it probably.

Comment: yep... see my second comment... thanks!

Comment: You need something like FEST https://code.google.com/archive/p/fest/ for tests which involve UI.

Comment: @Michal  thanks for the link: interesting.  The trouble is, I am using Jython and the Python unittest module, not a Java unit testing framework.  You're certainly right about things getting quite challenging when you are doing EDT in a unit test framework.  In fact Jython needs its own stuff, not least because Jython, unlike bog-standard CPython (only joking), is multi-threaded, and involves the EDT.  I am gradually evolving my own battery of techniques... which has the advantage that I understand what it's actually doing!

Comment: AFAIK you can use FEST regardless the unit test framework in use. FEST is just a library which allows for writing code doing user interaction - click a (JB)button, enter text in (JT)text field and so on. It is similar to Selenium used for Web UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.addActionListener( new ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
       if( e.getActionCommand().equals("CancelSelection") )
       {
            chooser.cancelSelection();
       }
    }
} );

public void forceCancel()
{
   ActionEvent e = new ActionEvent(chooser, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "CancelSelection");
   fireActionPerformed(e);
}

public void fireActionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
{
   ActionListener[] listeners = chooser.getActionListeners();
  for( ActionListener listener : listeners )
  {
     listener.actionPerformed( e );
  }
}
```

Using this code, you can call `forceCancel()` which fires an action event to automatically cancel the `JFileChooser`. You can include `forceCancel()` in your unit test.

( OR )

if you have component in your Jython call component.cancelSelection() by making is instance of check on the component.

Comment: Thanks... this is great... the only problem I have with it is that it is somewhat "testing-contrived"... in other words you have to add functionality to application code because you know that the testing code will want to do something which you will never do in the app code (i.e. cancel programmatically)...

Comment: ... Oh!  you found the answer though! just going `JFileChooser.cancelSelection()` (on its own) does exactly what I was asking to do: disposes of the dialog, returning `JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION`... Slightly misleading method name, perhaps!

Comment: Ok. Glad to know. I edited the answer to have an (OR) part. I thought you didn't have access to chooser in your unit testing code.